# How to read and write in the file using Path objects in java7?

Tags: java, file, path

I am working on a sorting project the specification is that I use path objects to work with files. The user will pass in Path object as parameter and then I need to get that path and write whatever it is in the file and store it there. 
I read lots of articles about Path class from Oracle but nothing helped I still don't understand how it is possible for me to use Path objects to read and write in the files.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The community cannot develop the whole project for you. Once you have started on a solution, you can ask a specific question if have problem with your code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried out the ```toFile()``` method for ```Path``` objects?

Comment: So, the immediate thing that jumps out at me is, you either need a `FileReader/Writer` or `FileInput/OutputStream`, which requires a `java.io.File` object - I would look for away to "convert" a `Path` object to a `File` object ... and oh look, it looks like someone else has already done that work for us - [`Path#toFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--)

Comment: Or Files.new[Input,Output]Stream(Path).

Comment: That's what I was looking for thank you  so much y'all